# Issue with Prod deployment from VS Code sfdx CLI

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli, cli

I'm trying to deploy my objects from VS Code to Prod. All my object is in Source format. But when I try to deploy, I get below error :

**sf:INVALID_OPERATION: INVALID_OPERATION: testLevel of NoTestRun cannot be used in production organizations**

And if I give RunLocalTest command it gives below error:

**ERROR running force:source:deploy:  ERROR: This command doesn't support wildcards. Remove the wildcard, and run the command again.
See --help for examples.**

Here is my command which I'm trying to run for Prod deployment

**sfdx force:source:deploy --sourcepath /Users/salesforceDeveloper/Desktop/SFDC Project/Prod Migration/force-app/main/default/objects -l RunLocalTests -u TargetEnv**

Also is there any command using which I can only validate my component in Prod?

Thanks

Comment: instead of -l RunLocalTests, try RunAllTests option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a space in your file path, so the CLI thinks you're trying to add multiple paths. Make sure you either quote:

```
"/Users/salesforceDeveloper/Desktop/SFDC Project/Prod Migration/force-app/main/default/objects"
```

Or backslash escape:

```
/Users/salesforceDeveloper/Desktop/SFDC\ Project/Prod\ Migration/force-app/main/default/objects
```

Or ideally, move the folder to a place without spaces. They tend to cause problems wherever you go. I recommend something like `/workspace/salesforce/migration` or something like that.

---

To verify only, use `-c` as a parameter:

```
sfdx force:source:deploy -p force-app/ -c -w 100 -l RunLocalTests -u targetOrg
```

I also recommend a wait time (`-w 100`) so that you can get feedback when the deployment is finished. If you don't use this parameter, you need to run `force:source:deploy:report` later, which is usually just annoying.

Comment: Okay so just to validate my components I have to use -c

Comment: Now instead of using whole path, I'm running the command from project folder